# Rotation matrix from plane A to B

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, 3d, rotations

I have two planes defined by two orthogonal vectors. Plane A is defined by vectors $A_x, A_y$ and B, $B_x, B_y$. I want to find the rotation matrix that would transform a point which has coordinates of $(x, y, z)$ to coordinates $(x', y', z')$ where original point have $(x'', y'')$ as components on Plane A and the transformed point would have $(x'', y'')$ on Plane B.

Comment: This is not possible in general. For the point and its image to have the same coordinates in their respective planes, i.e., for the image $x''A_x+y''A_y$ under a *rotation* to be $x''B_x+y''B_y$, you must have additional conditions, such as $\|A_x\|=\|B_x\|$ and $\|A_y\|=\|B_y\|$.

Comment: All vectors are unit vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 3 dimensions, there are infinitely many linear transformations that mat one plane onto another. We want to find one such transformation, defined by the matrix R, with the following properties:
$$R\mathbf{a}_x=\mathbf{b}_x\ ,\ R\mathbf{a}_y=\mathbf{b}_y$$
We can arbitrarily chose a third vector so that each set is a complete, linearly independent basis:
$$R\mathbf{a}_z=\mathbf{b}_z$$ 
where $\mathbf{a}_z$ and $\mathbf{b}_z$ are not contained within their respective planes. Let A be a matrix whose columns are $\mathbf{a}_x$, $\mathbf{a}_y$, and $\mathbf{a}_z$, and likewise with B. Then we have:
$$RA=B$$
Right multiplying by the inverse of A gives:
$$R=BA^{-1}$$
We can check to see if this gives the desired result:
$$(x,y,z)=x''\mathbf{a}_x+y''\mathbf{a}_y$$
$$(x',y',z')=R(x,y,z)=Rx''\mathbf{a}_x+Ry''\mathbf{a}_y$$
$$=x''R\mathbf{a}_x+y''R\mathbf{a}_y$$
$$=x''\mathbf{b}_x+y''\mathbf{b}_y$$
The choice of $\mathbf{a}_z$ and $\mathbf{b}_z$ does not affect what happens to points on the plane. It only determines how the "off-plane" component is transformed.

If R is to be a rotation matrix, A and B need to be orthogonal matrices, or some matrix multiple thereof. The conditions $||\mathbf{a}_x||=||\mathbf{b}_x||\ ,\ ||\mathbf{b}_y||=||\mathbf{a}_y||$, and $\mathbf{a}_x\cdot\mathbf{a}_y=\mathbf{b}_x\cdot\mathbf{b}_y$ must be met in order for this to be the case. Choosing $\mathbf{a}_z=\mathbf{a}_y\times\mathbf{a}_y$ and $\mathbf{b}_z=\mathbf{b}_y\times\mathbf{b}_y$ will then give the rotation matrix.

To see why this is, we need to use the property that the dot product is invariant under rotation. That is, for any vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}=(R\mathbf{u})\cdot(R\mathbf{v})$. From this we get 3 equalities:

$$\mathbf{a}_x\cdot\mathbf{a}_y=(R\mathbf{a}_x)\cdot(R\mathbf{a}_y)=\mathbf{b}_x\cdot\mathbf{b}_y$$

$$||\mathbf{a}_x||^2=\mathbf{a}_x\cdot\mathbf{a}_x=(R\mathbf{a}_x)\cdot(R\mathbf{a}_x)=\mathbf{b}_x\cdot\mathbf{b}_x=||\mathbf{b}_x||^2$$

$$||\mathbf{a}_y||^2=\mathbf{a}_y\cdot\mathbf{a}_y=(R\mathbf{a}_y)\cdot(R\mathbf{a}_y)=\mathbf{b}_y\cdot\mathbf{b}_y=||\mathbf{b}_y||^2$$

When choosing $\mathbf{a}_z$ and $\mathbf{b}_z$, we we will have 3 mode sets of dot products that need to be equal. It can be shown that $||\mathbf{a}_x\times\mathbf{a}_y||=||\mathbf{b}_x\times\mathbf{b}_y||$, and all of the other dot products are conveniently $0$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Simple and clear. It turns out that you don’t really need to normalize the columns of $A$ and $B$ when constructing a rotation. That’ll get sorted out when $A$ is inverted. Also, the restriction that the two bases be orthogonal/orthonormal can be relaxed somewhat as well: we want a rigid motion, so besides equal lengths we just need the angles between basis vector pairs to be equal.

Comment: @amd: on the other hand, if $A$ is known to be orthogonal/orthonormal (all three vectors perpendicular to each other, and of unit length), then $A^{-1} = A^T$. It might save a lot of effort, since one just uses $\mathbf{a}_x$, $\mathbf{a}_y$, and $\mathbf{a}_x\times\mathbf{a}_y$ for the *rows* of $A^{-1}$; for the final rotation matrix, a single 3×3 matrix multiplication then suffices. (Not that I expect this to matter, but I was surprised nobody mentioned it yet.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Good point! Avoiding an inversion is almost always a good thing, as far as I’m concerned.

Comment: @NominalAnimal My A plane is fixed, so decided to pre-calculate the inverse, I arrived to that solution.

Comment: I think it’s worth noting that this construction works in general: If you have a basis $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ for $\mathbf R^n$ and the images $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ under a linear transformation $T$, then the matrix of $T$ relative to the standard basis is $BA^{-1}$, where $A$ and $B$ are matrices with these vectors as their columns. One can think of this as applying a change of basis to the identity matrix.